# How to use wait or sleep for non angular pages in protractor?

Tags: protractor

I tried using browser.wait and browser.sleep and also added sleep in the config.js file but I haven't figured out how to make browser wait for non angular js page using protractor. So I need some solution so that I can make my browser wait

I tried using browser.wait and browser.sleep and also added sleep in the config.js file but I haven't figured out how to make browser wait for non angular js page using protractor

Comment: share your implementation and console error to give better view on the problem

Answer (score 0):

The difference between Protractor and WebdriverJS is that before performing each command Protractor waits for Angular specific $http and $timeout tasks to complete.

However, if you use Protractor in non-angular app you will notice that it simply doesn't do anything. As per my understanding, protractor keeps looking for these tasks without any luck

This feature can be manually disabled using `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)`.

Once you disable that, you can use `browser.sleep` and `browser.wait` regularly as you would use it on angular app.